# Are 10+ year contracts discouraged or prohibited in the NFL?

Tags: nfl, finances

In 2019, Mike Trout signed a 12-year, $430 million contract. This is on the heels of Bryce Harper signing a 13-year, $330 million contract. There have been several 10-year contracts signed by baseball players.

The longest contracts in the NFL during the 2018-2019 season are 6 years in length. The [longest contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_sports_contracts) in the NFL during the 2000s were 8-12 years in length.

Are 10+ year contracts discouraged or prohibited in the NFL? If discouraged, why? There were a few NFL contracts in the 10+ year range in the 2000s, but none since.

Comment: Technically, most NFL contracts aren't guaranteed, so they're more or less an one year contract with options.

Comment: It is also necessary to note that most players wont play over 13 or 14 years, so a 10 year contract would be discouraged, because if they made a small amount of money each year, which they signed for, if they get better and worth more, they still get that small amount of money each year.

Comment: @pboss3010 - I wouldn't say that's accurate; while most contracts will have a larger non-guaranteed portion both signing bonuses and a fully guaranteed element means teams would not want to ditch just any player year to year